# Two Node Fade In and Fade Out every minute

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to animate two panes using *fade-in* and *fade-out* animations. It should animate the first-pane and, after a few seconds, it should fade-out and animate second-pane, and so on.

I tried this code:

```
Thread thread;

@Override
public void run() {
   changingPane();
}

public void changingPane() {
    thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (;;) {
                if(mainController.getOpenPane()==0)
                {
                    mainController.nextPane();
                }
                else{
                    mainController.prevPane();
                }
            }
        }

    };
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Don't use threads for this. Use the [Animation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html).

Comment: how can i do that? do u have a sample for that?

Comment: The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm#JFXTE149) has plenty of samples. Try something and post a *specific* question if you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have two panes,

```
private Pane FIRST_PANE = new Pane();
private Pane SECOND_PANE = new Pane();
```

And add these methods for fade-in and fade-out the panes,

**Fade-In Method**

```
private void fadeInPane(Pane pane) {
     FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(2900), pane);
     fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
     fadeIn.setToValue(1);
     fadeIn.setOnFinished(e -> fadeOutPane(pane));
     fadeIn.play();
}
```

**Fade-out Method**

```
private void fadeOutPane(Pane pane) {
     FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1900), pane);
     fadeOut.setFromValue(1);
     fadeOut.setToValue(0);
     fadeOut.play();
}
```

Then call those methods as per your logic and need,

```
private void animatePane() {
    boolean first_active = true;

    Timeline clock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> {            

        if(first_active){
            fadeInPane(FIRST_PANE);
            first_active = false;
        }else{
            first_active = true;
            fadeInPane(SECOND_PANE);
        }
    }),
         new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(30))
    );
    clock.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    clock.play();
}
```